# ExtJs buffered grid row not being read by screenreader properly

Tags: extjs, accessibility, screen-readers, extjs-grid, extjs7-classic

I am using ExtJs 7.6 Classic and I am encountering an issue where screen readers like NVDA and Jaws are not properly announcing the row numbers of buffer grids. The buffer grid in kitchen sink seems to have the same issue: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#big-data-grid

I have tried setting the aria-label per cell, but that does not entirely override what the screen reader is announcing.

I was wondering if anyone encountered the same issue and was able to find a workaround?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add more details on how you are navigating with the screen reader?  TAB or simple up/down arrow keys to walk the DOM or table specific keys such as ctrl+alt+left/right?